How to achieve User impersonation through TenancyforLaravel?
I want my admin user to impersonate my standard user. I'm using TenancyforLaravel package (https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/features/user-impersonation/) with single database multi-subdomain installation.
My admin user want to ghost login to my tenant dashboard console and after that I want to logout as tenant user and switch back to my admin role profile.
I'm not able to achieve the impersonation. Can someone please guide me.

you cannot impersonate, can you show us the code? or gives any error? do route:list check if there is the route.

For ghost login, below is the code. Here "/home" can be replaced with your route where you want your user to be landed after impersonation but relative value only.
$user = User::find($id);
$tenant = $user->tenant;
$token = tenancy()->impersonate($tenant, $id, '/home');
$domain = $user->tenant_domain->domain;
$url = "http://$domain/impersonate/{$token->token}";
return redirect()->away($url);

This will give us the temporary login URL to achieve impersonation.

You can do the following:
Auth::login(User::find(1));
or
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
in a route to authenticate as that user, check the laravel docs.
Or you can use libraries like this
laravel-impersonate
to achieve what you expect with more to it (middleware, blades, configs etc). This is available till laravel 11.

This is just normal authentication, though - but the OP is asking about impersonation, which is more than just authentication: it impilies (or even requires) that additional actor claims are present which allow the user to revert back to their original session identity.

@Dai, edited my answer. A library that allows the impersonated user to revert to their original session. Hope it helps.

Thanks for sharing the answer. But, I'm using the different library to achieve the Multi-Tenancy as well. In that library there is a concept of user impersonation, I'm looking for help on that.

@SiddharthJain add to the question that lib to give more steps

@francisco TenancyforLaravel is the package name

APP_KEY should be same in .env for all installations then do the following
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::login($user);

or
Auth::loginUsingId(1);

explore the following links for detailed guide
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-instance
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-by-id
